# How to match "ss" against German sharp "s" in MySQL

Tags: mysql, internationalization

Users inputting in German might use either the spelling "Groß" or "Gross". By use of the utf8_unicode_ci collation, I can cause these two different spellings to sort in the right order.

But I would like to be able to search properly, so that if I have, for example, "Peter Groß" and "Martin Gross" in the database, I can find both names by doing a query like this one:

`select id from tperson where name like '%Gross%'`

But I can't figure out how to make the like operator work appropriately.

There's a similar problem where umlauted characters are sometimes written as an accented character followed by "e", as in "Müller" or "Mueller" being the same name.

Does anyone have any idea how to set up a "like" expression on MySQL which matches these characters correctly to their two character sequences?

Comment: Have you looked here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html

Comment: Tomaso Albinoni: yes, I have. It shows that I can do exact matches using the "=" operator and the correct collation, but that it's not possible to do wildcard matches because "LIKE" works one character at a time.

Comment: Exactly, so it looks like what you want is not possible. In addition to using `latin1_german2_ci` I would suggest storing first and last names separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Like** won't doit, try **regexp**

```
SELECT * FROM `ttt` WHERE c1 regexp 'gro(ss|ß)'
```